# Trying to calculate partial sums of e^10 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've written the function:

```
function [sum] = func(a,b)
sum = 0;
for i = 0:b
    sum = sum + ((a.^i)/(factorial(i)));
end
```

In the console, the commands I give are:

```
>> x = [10:10:100]
x =
    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100
```

And I get:

```
>> y = func(10,x)
y =
   1.2842e+04
```

Why am I not getting a vector? And why is the number so big (it's supposed to be close to 10)?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = @(x,i) (x.^i)./factorial(i)
r=f(10,0:50); %50 terms in taylor series more than enough for good approx.
cumsum(r)

1.0e+04 *

0.0001
0.0011
0.0061
0.0228
....
2.202646579479054
2.202646579480280
```

Verify

```
>> exp(10)
    2.202646579480672e+04
```

Comment: What I want is to approximate e^10 by summing at first 10 elements, then 20, then 30,... and to get a vector of approximations. Is that possible?

Comment: The vectors are all there. If you take the first 10 elements, this is partial sum of first 10. If you take the first 20 elements, this is partial sum of the first 20 elements, and so on. This is cumsum already.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't index `sum` with `i`, you return a single value.

Try instead:

```
function [sum] = func(a,b)

% Pre-allocate sum at the right size
sum = NaN(1,b+1);

% Compute
for i = 0:b
    sum(i+1) = sum(i+1) + ((a.^i)/(factorial(i)));
end
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I tried to index, it gives me this error: Attempted to access sum(2); index out of bounds because numel(sum)=1.

Comment: @John: Well, it should work, but I've just edited my answer with pre-allocation of `sum` (which is cleaner anyway)

Comment: @Ratbert: I suppose the OP wants to be able to input vector data for `b`. So maybe loop over `b`?

Comment: I marked this answer as correct at first, but in the end it doesn't work. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @John: I understand. There's no need to hurry in accepting an answer. Still, if an answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the checkmark. For now you could add a text to your question, that describes more exactly what you are trying to do. You probably want to add something like: *My function should accept a real scalar `a` and a vector of integers `b`. I except the output to be the vector `v` of partial sums of the exponential function `e^a`'s taylor series, such that `v(i)` is the partial sum from 0 up to `b(i)`.*